# Get cover art for each track with Spotify IOS SDK?

Tags: ios, spotify

I'm having a hard time finding the solution to get the cover art for each SPTPartialTrack with the Spotify iOS SDK.

I've looked through their docs and github demo project.  I can get the cover art using a separate call, parse for the image url, etc without using the SDK and I can get the album art of the current track from the currentTrackMetadata.  But I am trying to get the cover art for all the tracks to display on my tableview.

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SPTImage *image = track.album.largestCover;
```

Note that for table views you might want `smallestCover` instead. Also be aware that in some cases, there may be no cover art (you'll get `nil` back in this case).

Comment: Do track items in SPTListPage returned from performSearchWithQuery not have imageURLs?  selectedTrack.album.smallestCover.imageURL comes up empty for just the performSearchWithQuery.  Other parameters like titles, artists are coming in fine.  ImageURL for regular fetch such as  savedTracks also works fine.

Comment: I too am having trouble getting imageURL to return anything but nil. I have checked to make sure it is not due to my object being partial with both .requestItemAtURI() and .requestItemFromPartialObject() but whenever I call println(myObject.imageURL) it returns nil. Has anyone found a solution to this yet or is this just something broken in the SDK?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change from `SPTPartialTrack` to `SPTTrack` to get the cover art. You can do this using SPTRequest's  `requestItemFromPartialObject:withSession:callback:`
Then inside the callback you can access track.album.largestCover without it being `nil`.